# Confusion over application contexts, url-pattern, and RequestMapping - all in one project

Tags: spring-mvc

I've been trying to come up with a small test app that uses Spring 3(.1.1) MVC which supports multiple servlets to handle different URL patterns.

I created another bean to be autowired into the first servlet so I originally put the  for the DAO into the app-servlet.xml file since I wanted it limited to that servlet. Bu† when I did that I got an error about not being able to autowire the bean. If I move dhe  statements into the root-context.xml file then it worked.

Since I had 2 DispatcherServlets in the web.xml I had the url-pattern set to '/' for each. While I still had the  statements in the app-servlet.xml file, I changed the 2nd servlet's url-pattern to '/add' (also tried '/fred') and suddenly all is working as expected (2nd servlet called using /addperson - specified in RequestMapping of servlet).

When I put the  for the DAO into the root-context.xml, I was able to put the url-pattern back to '/'.

---

So in testing out this set up I had the following web.xml:

```
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>person</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/person-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>person</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The app-servlet.xml:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hh.builditup.controller" />
```

And person-servlet.xml:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hh.builditup.controller" />
```

root-context.xml:

```
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hh.builditup.dao" />
```

The 'app' servlet looks like:
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
private MyDAO myDAO;
/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
```

And finally the 'person' servlet:

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/addperson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

The DAO bean looks like:

```
@Component("myDAO")
public class MyDAO {

public MyDAO()
{
    System.out.println("created MyDAO object");
}
```

}

Can someone explain the interaction of url-pattern and RequestMapping that would produce these results? Why does the url-pattern have to be modified when a bean is restricted to one servlet versus being common? Also why does the changed to url-pattern not have an effect on the URL used to test the servlet?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: am I mistaken, or are both servlets handing the same url? And you should use one dispatcher servlet, and multiple controllers/request mappings.

Comment: They are handling the same url-pattern, but the 2nd servlet has a RequestMapping in it to change that. I'd like to know if I can use one dispatcher servlet with multiple controllers, but I've yet to come across an example that does this.

Comment: I've never seen multiple dispatcher servlets. That looks like a mistake. You want one dispatcher servlet, and multiple controllers, each handling their own route via RequestMapping.

Comment: It is legal to have multiple dispatcher servlets (Spring docs). I've recently changed my code to have a single one, but that doesn't answer the question of the behavior I observed.

Comment: if you're going to have multiple dispatcher servlets you would need to map them to different url patterns. As it is in your example, they both map to the root url.